# Dynamic Font Size Changes - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, widget, flutter-dependencies

Here, What I needed is :

**"Changing Overall Application Font's Size"** according to selected values from Application's Setting as below :

[image]

Here, I am **not talking about the support of font size in different screen sizes of device**. This is different thing, means font size **should change according to selected values** as 'small' , 'medium', 'large'.

Is there any better way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ChangeNotifierProvider](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html) and [ChangeNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html). This will allow to rebuild your entire app if you wrap your root widget i.e. MyApp which contains your `MaterialApp` within the ChangeNotifierProvider. Below is a sample piece of code:

```
// Changable Settings class
class AppSettings extends ChangeNotifier
{
   double fontSize;
   // TextStyle textStyle;
   
    void update() {     
        notifyListeners();
    }
}

// ChangeNotifier setup in main
main()
{
    runApp(
      MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => AppSettings()),
        ],
        child: MyApp(),
      ),
    );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   Consumer<AppSettings >(builder: (context, appSettings, child) {
      return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData().copyWith(   // Apply the theme to whole app
          textTheme: TextTheme(
            titleSmall: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .titleSmall
                .copyWith(fontSize: appSettings.fontSize), // Font Size apply
          ),
        ),
        home: homePage,
      );
    });
  }
}

// Get the change from user from the settings page
class SettingsPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   ...
  }
  
  onSave(){
    var appSettings = Provider.of<AppSettings>(context);
    appSettings.fontSize = fontSize; // from the UI
    appSettings.update();
  }
}
```

Hope it gives some start point to you.